# Create .NET BackgroundService dynamically and manage the lifetime

Tags: c#, .net, background-service

I have a background service in .NET ([BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1))

```
public class MyService<TElement, TKey, TValue> : BackgroundService
```

It works find in Startup and I have set up as follows:

```
_serviceCollection.AddHostedService<MyService<TElement, TKey, TValue>>();
```

`_serviceCollection` is [IServiceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicecollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instance.

That works fine and great.

I am authoring some test and I want to create instances of `MyService` Background Service dynamically based on Web API calls. I already create them in memory triggered by web API call.

I have three calls: Create, Start, and Stop. One will create the background service in memory and the other will start and stop respectively.

I have this call to start the background service.

```
 [HttpPost("myservice/perf/start")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> StartServiceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, [FromBody] ServiceParameters params)
        {
            await Task.Run( () => {
                // Start the consumer service if not already started
                // retrieve service instance 
                var _myServiceInstance = GetMyService( params );

                _myServiceInstance .StartAsync(new CancellationToken());  
            });

        }
```

I am not sure it is working. Even though I see breakpoint in the `ExecuteAsync` method that belongs to my background service, I can't step through line by line, it just disappears. I am not sure if I am starting it correctly or if it gets cancelled when the HTTP request is closed (Hence I am using new CancellationToken rather than passing the one from Controller POST call).

I want to start the background service asynchronously. I also have another Controller call to stop MyService (it will call the StopAsync call)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `BackgroundService` is a part of ASP.NET Core. You should not be calling `StartAsync`, that's part of the startup routines of a `HostedService` when injected via DI (the framework maintains the lifecycle of your service). As far as I know, this is not how it was intended to be used.

Comment: I understand the HostedService part. I am using it correctly at startup as shown in question. However, the controller I have is intended to test various background service instances with different configurations. What do you suggest

Comment: I suggest you abstract all the business logic from your BackgroundService to another service -- probably a transient service. Then inject that transient service into your BackgroundService and your testing code.

Comment: I want to implement the same thing as you, Background services dynamically, did you get the solution? do you run AddHostedService every time you add a service?